# options.ResolveConflictingActions not working in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore，how to fix it？

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-2.0

in my `Startup.cs`,add swagger

[image]
and use custom configuration

[image]

but i'm still receive exception and not in 'break point'
[image]

[image]

any help?thanks

Comment: Please Decorate your  `GetTable()` action method with a route attribute, e.g.: `HttpGet("Table")`